# PostgreSQL ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR: must appear in the GROUP BY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have got difficulties group in PostGreSQL. My code below

```
Invoice.select("customer_id, due_date, sum(balance) AS total_balance, total_mount").group(:customer_id)
```

I have got the errors

```
  Invoice Load (1.8ms)  SELECT customer_id, due_date, sum(balance) AS total_balance, total_amount FROM "records" WHERE "records"."type" IN ('Invoice') GROUP BY "records"."customer_id"
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "records.due_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
enter code here
LINE 1: SELECT customer_id, due_date, sum(balance) AS total_balance,...
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for @slicedpan for the solution. I have update like below code.

```
Invoice.select("customer_id, MAX(due_date), SUM(balance) AS total_balance").group(:customer_id)
```

I have read many of articles about that but It still show the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to the fact that Postgres doesn't know what to do with the due_date column. The query you have written is basically:

> for each customer, show me the total sum of the balances for all their invoices, and the due date for one of their invoices.

The problem here is that in PostgreSQL you have to be explicit about which invoice you want to show the `due_date` of, whereas in MySQL or SQLite it will pick one (can't remember how off the top of my head). In this case I think it would make more sense to leave out the due_date from the select, otherwise use `MAX(due_date)` to get the most recent, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you. I want to try first.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same functionality as MySQL/SQLite if you do it like this:

```
Invoice.select("DISTINCT ON (customer_id) customer_id, due_date, sum(balance) over(partition by customer_id) AS total_balance, total_mount")
```

It will sum balance and select "random" due_date/total_mount for each customer_id. Just like non-standard GROUP BY possible in those 2 other RDBMS.